# Taking the derivative of square root of y by squaring the equation instead of using implicit differentiation

Tags: derivatives

For an equation like:
$$
\sqrt{y}+\sqrt{x}=1
$$

Why can't I isolate the "square root of $y$" and then raise both sides of the equation by the power of $2$? That will get $y$ outside of the radical, but for some reason the result is not the same as with using implicit differentiation. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With implicit differentiation we get
$$
\frac{y'}{2\sqrt{y}}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{x}}=0
$$
so
$$
y'=-\frac{\sqrt{y}}{\sqrt{x}}=\frac{\sqrt{x}-1}{\sqrt{x}}=1-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}
$$
By doing $y=(1-\sqrt{x})^2=1-2\sqrt{x}+x$
we get
$$
y'=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}+1
$$
as before.

Comment: Oh, so it's just a matter of algebra manipulation :|
Thank you!!